# Add digital signature to PDF, loaded using remote server

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature

Is it possible in Android to set digital signature in a PDF loading from URL inside my Android application (open source)? That is:

- I want to load a PDF URL from server (not from SD card)
- Then ask the user to sign on a canvas
- And once they sign on the canvas, ask them to drag and place the signature image on the PDF (inside content, and in proper position of signature).

Currently I'm using `Google Doc Url` to load the PDF, and is loading the PDF. If there any better open source solutions, please refer them also, because I would like to load the PDF inside my application page (not inside drive UI).

```
String pdf = "http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf";
webview.loadUrl("http://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=" + pdf);
```

[image]

Please guide...

Comment: what kind of library are you using?OMG what a bad reputation,no answer accepted.Gives me a headache just looking at your questions

Comment: You call the signature you want to add a *"digital signature"* and also use that tag. But that term usually is associated with mathematical signing schemes, public-private-key-pairs, X509 certificates, etc. (have a look at the hover text of the [tag:digital-signature] tag) but that is not what you want. Thus, you might want to update your question text and tags to better reflect what you want.